# DataGridView selecting "Complete Row"

Tags: .net, gridview

In Windows .NET gridview - if a grid is readonly; when I click, a cell is selected; I want complete row to be highlighted instead of just cell.

any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try it like this:

```
dataGridView1.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect;
```